# Making sense of makefile flags

Tags: makefile

**Input**: makefile that doesn't point to a C# solution
**Output**: new makefile, solution and project (.csproj)
-> the makefile points to a solution, which points to a project

There are many makefile flags, such as:

```
# sample.makefile
# author: me

LIBRARY_A = YES
LIBRARY_B = YES
LIBRARY_C = YES
```

These flags, I believe, point to **.def**'s or .**dll**'s. My script will read a makefile flag, then add the correct XML tags within the csproj file to capture the project references. Two questions that I kindly request your help with:

1) how do I figure out what these flags point to?
2) is it OK to just include **all** of the libraries, i.e. skip the work of figuring out which libraries need to be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Those are not just some flags, those are *variables*. Whenever `${LIBRARY_A}` for example is used, the value is expanded to its associated value.

```
all:
        echo You chose to set LIBRARY_A to ${LIBRARY_A}
```

2.
To answer that, the documentation of the project should be consulted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that you're telling me to check my requirements for #2, but is #2 a feasible route? I'm just curious if including all of these libraries will cause any performance issues...

Comment: It depends on the remaining Makefile and what it does. (Setting to YES/NO might cause additional code to be sourced in any way, etc.)